# Netbeans MPI c++ how to start?

Tags: c++, netbeans, ubuntu, mpi

Hello everyone I just staring developing c++ under netbeans/ubuntu(x64) and now I am staring with MPI. How can I compile, test,run mpi applications under. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Till now, I've found only this IDE for MPI on Linux: Geany (a tutorial is [here](http://auriza.site40.net/notes/mpi/openmpi-on-ubuntu-904/).)
But I keep searching...
If anyone find better IDE, please share under this question...

Answer (score 2):

There is an Eclipse plug-in for parallel programming, including MPI: http://www.eclipse.org/ptp/

Answer (score 1):

To build, change the C++ compiler in NetBeans's C/C++ options to be `/path/to/mpicc`.

As for running, MPI applications are usually invoked with `mpirun`. This is done either via the command line (on your PC) or via a batch description file (on a cluster with OpenPBS, LoadLeveler, or similar scheduler). I've never tried to run MPI via an IDE, though NetBeans does have an option for the debugger command, so you might be able to try that and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for reply. May be is some others IDE more useful for c++\MPI under linux?

Comment: @Joe I've never heard of an IDE for MPI. That's an interesting prospect though. Sounds like something RogueWave or Portland Group could be coaxed into doing. Otherwise, might have to write an extension for your editor of choice. (Seems like it would be straightforward with Emacs or a similarly extensible platform.)

Comment: I have tried to modify `Properties=>Run=>Run Command` to `mpirun -hosts h1,h2,h3 ${OUTPUT_PATH} -p param` it runs fine the program on all the hosts. But it doesn't attach gdb to the program.