# Debugging in parallel mode using Netbeans

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, mpi

I want to debug a c++ code with Netbeans. I can use the debugger in sequential mode but I dont know how to debug it when I want to run it in parallel (MPI). I would be grateful if anyone help me on this problem.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361675/netbeans-mpi-c-how-to-start?rq=1 ?

Comment: No, actually I am able to compile and run the MPI code with NetBeans. I want more information on how to the MPI debugging.